# Random.nextInt() producing very similar numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, random, time

I've written a class to generate a random Int Array with numbers between (0-100) in Java:

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class RandomClass{
        private Random randNum;

        public RandomClass() {
            randNum = new Random();
        }

        public int[] generateRandomArray(int arraySize){
            int[] theArray = new int[arraySize];
            for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
                theArray[i] = randNum.nextInt(101);
            }
            return theArray;        
        }
    }
```

For some reason, when I run my program I get a similar sequence of numbers repeated within my Array output each time.

Here is a sample showing 3 runs of the program at a different time:

```
Array result: [65, 71, 71, 71, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78]

Array result: [40, 55, 55, 55, 62, 62, 62, 70, 77, 77]

Array result: [56, 56, 73, 73, 73, 73, 77, 77, 77, 77]
```

Why is this happening? Is it because the Random function is based upon time and the loop is running too quickly before it can return a new 'random' number? Or some other reason? How do I fix this?

Comment: I can rule out one speculation: `Random.nextInt` is not based on time. It is a linear congruence generator that generates a predictable but random-looking sequence of numbers based on the seed. The seed may be based on time, but in your code, that is done only once, when the `Random` object is first created. Are these three runs for the same instance of `RandomClass`? Or are you creating a new instance for each run?

Comment: Can you show also the part where you call `generateRandomArray` and print it ? I'm thinking you may be creating your `RandomClass` object each time you need a number.

Comment: @TedHopp Ah thanks for clarifying that. I'll make an edit now showing more of my code. Unfortunately, I can't post the entire source as this is an assignment.

Comment: Well, the short answer is that you haven't shown us the portion of the code that has the problem.  If you can't post any more of your code, then you're not going to get a correct answer here.

Comment: I tried you code in my jdk , its working fine. [9, 45, 13, 21, 81, 62, 46, 99, 17, 32] [15, 56, 69, 20, 23, 24, 2, 47, 19, 46] [89, 44, 56, 47, 35, 52, 97, 20, 67, 91] [53, 22, 63, 17, 57, 41, 42, 15, 23, 27] [80, 40, 80, 25, 96, 55, 23, 17, 65, 50] [69, 14, 88, 41, 46, 5, 92, 2, 100, 53] [46, 7, 97, 93, 14, 65, 51, 24, 88, 62] [32, 84, 52, 44, 60, 13, 84, 64, 0, 43] [37, 80, 34, 72, 19, 19, 64, 16, 88, 33] [15, 13, 92, 18, 75, 90, 25, 8, 33, 86]. Which jdk version you are using ?

Comment: I suspect that the problem is in how you are printing the results. Can you post that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, just add a main method, and you will see:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int[] ints = new RandomClass().generateRandomArray(10);
        System.out.println("RandomClass::main: ints = " + Arrays.toString(ints));
    }
}
```

It prints very different random numbers. The problem is somewhere else.